# How to include layouts in DrawerLayout programatically and smooth dragging of navigation view?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_bar_main, null);
        drawer.addView(child);
```

I used this code to programatically add different Childs to drawer layout. When I add child programatically means navigation drawer is not working properly I mean it can be dragged out but not able to drag in.When I touch out side means it is closing.Can anybody know how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including in drawer layout try to include in Coordinator layout.